# SQL query between date/time with different fileds for date and times

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, time

I have a SQL Server 2014 database with 2 fields: 
 - one of type `date` for the record date 
 - one of type `time` for the record time.

I want to retrieve records from the table between 2 dates/ times.
Example: from 2015-01-01 at 16:00 until 2015-01-02 at 08:00.

I tried

```
SELECT...
Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-02'
AND Time BETWEEN '16:00' AND '08:00'
```

This fails, as expected.

Can I do what I want or only if I use a single field for date and time (`datetime` type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the fields:

```
WHERE cast(date as datetime)+cast(time as datetime) between
'2015-01-01 16:00' AND '2015-01-02 8:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will only work if want to find records within a certain time window between certain days. E.g. during office hours between 13 and 17 July.

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2015-07-13' AND '2015-07-17'
AND CONVERT(Time, [Time]) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '16:00'
```

And since your start `Time` value is greater than your end time value, you will not get any results until you combine the date and time into one value like:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DateTime, [Date]) + CONVERT(DateTime, [Time])
BETWEEN '2015-01-01 16:00' AND '2015-01-02 08:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate and then convert the fields together to form a `datetime` as such:

```
select *
from thing
where convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), myDate) + ' ' + convert(varchar(10), myTIme)) between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-02 01:01:00'
```

note I'm assuming your date is in a `date` column, and your time is in a `time` column

see fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a308/8

If most of your queries are going to be on a `datetime` rather than a `date` or a `time`, consider adding a `datetime` column instead, as queries like the above tend to be inefficient due to needing to run a convert on unnecessary rows in order to determine if they should be included.  Perhaps a computed column could help with this as well.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works great. I will take in consideration your advice on adding a `datetime` column. I have made already some tests and I can move from one colum of `date` type plus a column of `time` type to a single column of `datetime` without loosing data.